# javascript работает на онлайн редакторе, но на локальном компьютере нет

Tags: javascript, html, google-chart

Недавно я спрашивал здесь, как правильно подключить скрипт с google charts к форме с вводимыми данными,мне подсказали полностью рабочий скрипт. Но он работает только на онлайн редакторах (jsfiddle, jsbin). При открытии файла браузером с компьютера (проверял chrome и firefox), скрипт как и раньше не работает, подскажите, пожалуйста, причину.

```js
document.getElementById('drawChart').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
  });

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    var mushrooms = document.getElementById('mushrooms').value;
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', parseInt(mushrooms)],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
      'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
      'width': 400,
      'height': 300
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<!--Form-->
Mushrooms: <input id="mushrooms">
<button id="drawChart">build</button>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: А интернет при этом подключен?

Comment: @RuslanMelnichenko, хороший вопрос?)))

Comment: скопировал себе, у меня все работает

Comment: @Air Ну а вдруг он пробует на компьютере который не подключен к интернету

Comment: @RuslanMelnichenko, может быть...)))

Comment: Скачай библиотеку и загружай его по локалке

Comment: интернет подключен...